# ExoPlayer doesn't play video

Tags: android, user-interface, exoplayer

I've done the next implementation of ExoPlayer for playing HLS:

```
SimpleExoPlayer player;

player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(mContext, trackSelector, loadControl);

                    Handler mHandler = new Handler();
                    String userAgent = Util.getUserAgent(mContext, "appName");
                    DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory(
                            userAgent, null,
                            DefaultHttpDataSource.DEFAULT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS,
                            1800000,
                            true);
                    HlsMediaSource mediaSource = new HlsMediaSource(Uri.parse(URL), dataSourceFactory, 1800000,
                            mHandler, null);
                    player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
                    player.prepare(mediaSource);
```

Then I've found that my code playing only audio and I was searching till I found this:

```
PlayerView playerView;
playerView = view.findViewById(R.id.pView);
playerView.setPlayer(player);
```

layout with playerView:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/RLteleNew"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/gray21"
    >

...

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/LLtopnew2"
        >

        <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
        android:id="@+id/pView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:visibility="visible">
    </com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView>
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

In all of examples this is solution for playing video but when I adding this to my code - Exoplayer playing nothing.

What should I edit in my code?

**Found one more good guide for ExoPlayer implementation:**
https://exoplayer.dev/hello-world.html

Seems like I have done everything right.

Does anybody have ideas why it is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement this in Activity, not in adapter class.